# Docker Insecure registry , ubuntu 14.0.4 trusty , request canceled time out awaiting headers

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

i created a registry using below command -

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry

if i use command

> Docker pull localhost:5000/…

everything works

but if i use

> Docker pull ipaddress:5000/…

everything fails

i tried editing /etc/default/docker file with DOCKER_OPTS that made docker service to crash

i added /etc/docker/daemon.json file with insecure registry entries but even that i get below error on docker pull/push -

> request canceled time out awaiting headers

i am stuck here need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to fix the issue , it was due to missing no_proxy which when i added for my ipaddress it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the registry as an [insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) by editing the deamon.json file. By default, when connecting to a registry on localhost there is no need to have TLS certificates configured.

However, when you try to connect to remote registry and it is insecure, you need to add an insecure registry line for the remote registry.

Comment: i mentioned that in question that i had tried that and after that instead of tls handshake failure i am getting request canceled time out awaiting headers